# What is the difference between promoting a release, and creating a new one?

Tags: bamboo

When running a deployment in bamboo, it gives the option between '*promoting'* a release or creating an old one. Is this just jargon for 'reuse' or is something else happening?

I've not found anything in the Atlassian docs, and only [this](http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/5413-bamboo-best-practice-create-new-releases-or-promote) came up:

> You should create a new release if there were changes in your code since the last version. If you need to promote code from one environment to another, using the "Promote" feature is definitely the way to go.

I think that makes sense if you replace 'promote' with 'reuse' makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reuse some old releases, then you tell Bamboo promote(reuse) the previously built releases. In this sense, with promote Bamboo means reuse.

### [image: Deployment task]

From Build Result you can always create new release to deploy, but always the latest build result.

Comment: Why is this the default option?

Comment: I guess that Bamboos thought was using the existing release to make deployment on different servers is the most frequent use case, but maybe they are wrong with that. :)

Comment: Yes, a release is only dependent on which build result it uses.

Comment: @VictorioBerra it is default because this is how most deployments work. You deploy to one environment like 'integration' to test that all changes are good, then you *promote* it to the next stage like 'staging' in it's exact state (i.e. you don't need another build), then if it passes, you *promote* the same build to production. It's good for consistency sake. This of course assumes that all environments use the same build parameters which is highly dependent on your best practices which is a different discussion.